Pynput not recognizing inputs when terminal is focused
I'm on Ubuntu 24, using Python 3.12. I have a basic Python script with pynput that stops the program execution when the up arrow is pressed. Running this script in Pycharm has no problems, but in a terminal window it doesn't recognize the inputs unless the terminal is unfocused. Here's my code:
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

stop = False
def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    if key == Key.up:
        global stop
        stop = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
    listener.start()
    while not stop:
        pass              # some other code goes here

Replacing listener = Listener(on_press=on_press) with
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()

still doesn't work in the terminal until unfocused.

I tested your code; it works fine for me. I think that it has something to do with your app configurations on Ubuntu, because it should still work whether the terminal is focused or not.

what terminal do you use in Ubuntu? maybe all problem is in terminal. Maybe it use non-standard method to get keys and it blocks other programs. Maybe you will need different terminal

Also, what happens when you run this in the shell? I agree with @furas, this most likely has something to do with the terminal app. (Also, importing KeyCode from pynput.keyboard is unnecessary, so an edit would be appreciated :).)

@5rod literally nothing. It just waits on a blank screen forever, until CTRL + C is pressed.
